# How to avoid duplicate string values in a bubble sort algorithm?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, duplicates, bubble-sort

I'm trying to figure out on how can i **avoid printing duplicate names** in my sorting algorithm.

The reason i'm ignoring the vacant string is that the system i'm implementing, is a ticket booking system which displays a list of only names instead of the vacant slots.

Can some help me please ?

```
String[] name={"fiona","vacant","allen","fiona","david","vacant","vacant"};
        for (int i = 0; i <= (name.length-1); i++){
            for (int j = i+1; j < name.length; j++ ){
                if (name[i].compareTo(name[j])>0) {
                    String temp = name[i];
                    name[i] = name[j];
                    name[j] = temp;
                }
            }
            if (!name[i].equals("vacant")) {
                System.out.println(name[i] + " ");
            }
        }
```

Comment: If you're really "implementing" this system yourself and are not doing this for homework...then do not write your own sort algorithm.. don't reinvent the wheel

Comment: This is a common sorting algorithm if you haven't noticed , i only made a slight change to this code which excluded a common element "vacant".

Comment: A common O(n^2) bad sorting algorithm that nobody uses except in homework assignments.

Comment: But this is the most common sorting method, its just that my assignment restricts me from using built in java functions.

Comment: Lol as I said, if it's an assignment than that is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if the name you are printing is the same as the previous one:

```
String[] name={"fiona","vacant","allen","fiona","david","vacant","vacant"};
for (int i = 0; i <= (name.length-1); i++){
    for (int j = i+1; j < name.length; j++ ){
        if (name[i].compareTo(name[j])>0) {
            String temp = name[i];
            name[i] = name[j];
            name[j] = temp;
        }
    }
    if (!name[i].equals("vacant") && (i == 0 || !name[i-1].equals(name[i]))) {
        System.out.println(name[i] + " ");
    }
}
```